# Cannot find module while importing styles from module.scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

I'm only starting learning **React** and faced an issue while importing **styles** from `'./TodoOutput.module.scss'`:

**Error from `TodoOutput.tsx`:**

```
Cannot find module ./TodoOutput.module.scss or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

even though file `TodoOutput.module.scss` exists, and both `scss` and `sass` packages added into both **package.json** and **package-lock.json**

Here is `TodoOutput/` directory:

[image]

Review **[package.json](https://controlc.com/ac71eb40)**

Review **[package-lock.json](https://controlc.com/1d947eba)**

Review **[tsconfig.json](https://controlc.com/6b27f3dc)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the problem.
You need to create a Global.d.ts file inside yours src folder and add following lines.

```
declare module "*.module.css";
declare module "*.module.scss";
```

Answer (score 0):

The import looks ok, but when you set paths in tsconfig you need to add baseUrl for example src.

If this does not help, try renaming the file, maybe you changed the keyboard when naming

Comment: Unfortunately none of the advices helped